# Asymptotic behaviour of Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous.

Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\sin nx dx =0$

I wasn't able to solve it. The best upper bound I arrive at is $
\frac{2M}{\pi}$, Is there any other way?

Comment: This is just a special case of Riemann Lebesgue Lemma. See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Lemma

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick that I learned in a harmonic analysis class: Let $M \geq 0$ be a bound of $f$. Then by using the substitution $x \mapsto x+\frac{\pi}{n}$,

\begin{align*}
\left| 2\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right|
&= \left| \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{-\frac{\pi}{n}}^{1-\frac{\pi}{n}} f\left(x+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\sin(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \\
&\leq \frac{2\pi M}{n} + \int_{0}^{1-\frac{\pi}{n}} \left| f(x) - f\left(x+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right| \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Now use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, 1]$ to show that this bound converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Good trick. For now, I am waiting if someone else is showing another trick. I will accept the answer by morning. It helps me a lot thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $x\rightarrow x+2\pi/n$??

Comment: @CloudJR We need half-period of that sine to introduce "cancellation".

Comment: what you mean by cancellation I haven't got could you please explain

Comment: @CloudJR If you use $x\mapsto x+\frac{2\pi}{n}$ instead, the you do not pick up that precious negative sign that allows "almost cancellation" between $f(x)$ and its nearby value $f(x+\frac{\pi}{n})$.

Comment: Oh, got it Thanks